# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error! AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've encountered a problem that I can't seem to fix and I hope someone out there can help me out!

I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to instantiate module musicApp due to:
{1}
```

This is the function I'm using:

```
'use strict';

var angular = angular

    .module('angular', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
    .config (function ($RouteProvider){

    $RouteProvider

        .when ('/', {
        templateULR: '/templates/list-artists.html'
    })
        .when ('/add-artist', {
            templateUrl: '/add-artist.html'
    })
        .when ('/artist-details/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'artist-details.html'
    })
        .otherwise ({redirectTo: '/'});
})
    .constant ('author', 'Sekret Doge'
```

This is where I'm calling this function:

```
'use strict';

angular.controller('ListArtistsController',
    function ListArtistsController($scope, artistData) {

        $scope.artists = artistData.getAllArtists();

    });
```

And this is my html file, that's supposed to show the information I require:

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="ListArtistsController">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
            <div class="col-md-4" text-center>
                <h2> <a href="#artist-details/{{ artist.id }}"> {{ artist.name }}</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'll even give the script sources because some people are having problems thanks to them:

```
    <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/PageController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ListArtistsController.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

If there are anymore codes or files missing from this post that you need to look at, just tell me to edit the post!

getAllArtists function:

```
'use strict';

angular.factory('artistData', function ($resource) {

        var resource = $resource('/data/artist/:id', {id: '@id'});

    return {
        getArtist: function (id) {
            return resource.get ({id: id});
        },

        saveArtist: function (artist) {

            artist.id = 999;
            resource.save (artist);
        },

        getAllArtists: function() {

            return resource.query();

        }
    }
});
```

PageController:

```
'use strict';

angular.controller('PageController',
    function PageController($scope) {

        $scope.author = "Sekret Doge";
        $scope.date = {
            year: 2014,
            month: 4,
            day: 4
        }

    }
);
```

app:

```
'use strict';

var angular = angular

    .module('angular', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
    .config (function ($RouteProvider){

    $RouteProvider

        .when ('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/list-artists.html'
    })
        .when ('/add-artist', {
            templateUrl: '/add-artist.html'
    })
        .when ('/artist-details/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'artist-details.html'
    })
        .otherwise ({redirectTo: '/'});
})
    .constant ('author', 'Sekret Doge');
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: What does your getAllArtists(); function look like?

Comment: I've placed the code in the post

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. What does your PageController.js and app.js files look like?

Comment: I guess then we're on the same page, i've added the code in the post

Comment: What does the HTML look like where you are referencing your PageController?

Comment: This is the html:
http://jsfiddle.net/295Uu/17/
I've removed the html and head tags because jsfiddle doesnt need them

Comment: Hmmm, at this point I'd suggest starting with an empty jsfiddle and add one thing at a time to it until the first point where you start getting that error.

Comment: I'll try, thanks for helping, sry i couldnt help much but im new with angular and that stuff so trying to understand all these problems is really tough...

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately I'm new with it too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't loading the ngRoute javascript. It's in a separate file.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: It says "Failed to instantiate module musicApp due to:
{1}"
I added the ngRoute but it still says it :/

Comment: Also, ngResource is loaded from a separate file. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

Comment: Am i missing a file that i need to add to this post to look at?

Comment: I don't know if missing css files would cause a problem like that. I  can't think of any others.

Oh, I'm not sure when it is exactly needed but you might try also adding the bootstrap template file.  

ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Comment: I dont have a file like that, i only have bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js

Comment: I got my version of it using Bower but you can find out more about it from here: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#build-files

Comment: Ok, i added the 2 new bootstrap tpls files but this time it says:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.min.js:1
and the old error is still there :/

Comment: The bootstrap.js file that you added is the non-minified version of the bootstrap.min.js file you already have.  

Also, you are probably using version 10 of bootstrap. Try downloading it again from here so that the template file matches your bootstrap.min.js file
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
and select yes for "include templates". 

But that probably still won't fix your original problem.

Comment: The line templateULR: '/templates/list-artists.html' should be templateUrl: '/templates/list-artists.html'

Answer (score 0):

The following library in the script tag in your HTML needs included in your .js.

```
lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.min.js
```

at the top of app.js add ui.bootstrap.

```
var angular = angular

.module('angular', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```